# How to know what file is currently playing in ffmpeg concat playlist?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, bash-scripting

I have a Docker Alpine Linux container with ffmpeg streaming bunch of video files to YouTube.
Videos are injected through `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt` where `mylist.txt` contains video file paths.

I need to send messages about the current playing file. Is there any way to understand which file is playing now?

- I checked ffmpeg documentation and didn't find it, but maybe I missed a way to run a script from ffmpeg on playlist switching?
- Or may be some ffmpeg console output mode which prints current file name?
- Or is there any way to get files currently opened by ffmpeg?
- Or maybe catching an event when ffmpeg opens a file?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by using using the `-v debug` flag. Its very verbose but when it opens the next file from the playlist it will have the output below:

`[NULL @ 0x52f21478d4c2] Opening '<FILENAME>' for reading`

To filter the output 'live' in the command line, I used the method I read from this post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213002

Grep will filter the verbose output and only show what file was last opened in the CLI. Example below:

```
script -c "ffmpeg -v debug -f concat -i playlist.txt <OTHER FLAGS>" /dev/null | grep 'reading'
```